# Is there different meaning between the following sentences?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> 1. I don't have any cameras.
> 2. I don't have any camera.

Comment: What do you think the difference might be?

Comment: Do you mean the two sentences are correct and have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is grammatically correct. Using the word "any" implies that the noun that follows it (in this case "camera") will be plural.

Note: "any" can be used with singular nouns afterwards, but usually (dare I say only) when that noun is intangible, for example "I don't have any knowledge on the subject."